# How to set browser language in selenium remote webdriver capabilities

Tags: selenium, webdriver, remotewebdriver

I need to start Firefox / Chrome using remote webdriver with a specific browser language.  I know how to do it while running locally.  But is it possible to start a remote webdriver with specifying browser language.

Answer (score 0):

This is how object creation done is RemoteWebDriver,

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:PORT_NUMBER/"), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
```

Profiller is the key here,

```
var fp = new FirefoxProfile();
fp.SetPreference("intl.accept_languages", "en-au");
desiredCap.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName,fp.ToBase64String());
```

your code seems specific to chrome so you can use this, I hope this might help you,

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--lang=zh"); // this sets US english 
desiredCap.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:PORT_NUMBER/"), desiredCap.chrome());
```

Possible duplicate of [How to set Browser Language using RemoteWebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808209/how-to-set-browser-language-using-remotewebdriver)