# Setting language for Remotewebdriver - BrowserStack endpoint

Tags: c#, selenium, browserstack, remotewebdriver

I wish to run my selenium tests in a different browser language.  I have tried two SO answers and even the BrowserStack support without success.

I had hoped this would be a quick and easy fix, but what looks like simple code is failing in a manner I do not understand.  Can anyone either provide a working code snippet, or a good idea where this one is going wrong?

[This answer][How to set Browser Language using RemoteWebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808209/how-to-set-browser-language-using-remotewebdriver) and [this answer][How to set browser language in selenium remote webdriver capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52751691/how-to-set-browser-language-in-selenium-remote-webdriver-capabilities) have both been tried in the following code:

```
            DesiredCapabilities DesCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();

            DesCaps.SetCapability("browserstack.user", "your_user");
            DesCaps.SetCapability("browserstack.key", "your_key");


            FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
            fp.SetPreference("intl.accept_languages", "en-US");
            DesCaps.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, fp);

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--lang=en-DE");
            DesCaps.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);


            RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub/"), DesCaps, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(500));

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");

            Console.WriteLine("Completed!");
            Console.ReadKey();
```

I receive an exception when I try to start the driver:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The property '#/' contains additional properties ["BinaryLocation", "LeaveBrowserRunning", "Arguments", "Extensions", "DebuggerAddress", "MinidumpPath", "PerformanceLoggingPreferences", "UseSpecCompliantProtocol", "BrowserName", "BrowserVersion", "PlatformName", "AcceptInsecureCertificates", "UnhandledPromptBehavior", "PageLoadStrategy", "Proxy"] outside of the schema when none are allowed in chromeOptions
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
```

Answer (score 1):

BrowserStack Support kindly supplied two working examples:

```
        {
            IWebDriver driver;


            FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

            options.AddAdditionalCapability("browser", "firefox", true);
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("os", "Windows", true);
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("os_version", "10", true);
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("browser_version", "63.0", true);
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("build", "BuildName", true);
            options.SetPreference("intl.accept_languages", "de");

            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://your_username:your_access_key@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub/"),
                                         options.ToCapabilities());


            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            Console.WriteLine(driver.Title);

            IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
            query.SendKeys("Browserstack");
            query.Submit();
            Console.WriteLine(driver.Title);

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.amazon.in");
            Console.WriteLine(driver.Title);

            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
```

and in Chrome:

```
  IWebDriver driver;


            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

            options.AddAdditionalCapability("browser", "chrome", true);
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("os", "Windows", true);
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("os_version", "10", true);
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("browser_version", "69.0", true);
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("build", "BuildName", true);

            options.AddArgument("--lang=de");

            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://your_username:your_access_key@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub/"),
                                         options.ToCapabilities());


            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            Console.WriteLine(driver.Title);

            IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
            query.SendKeys("Browserstack");
            query.Submit();
            Console.WriteLine(driver.Title);

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.amazon.in");
            Console.WriteLine(driver.Title);

            driver.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet, I see you have specified the browser options for Chrome and Firefox in the same script. You will need to have a separate test script for Chrome and Firefox.

-For creating a session on Chrome browser include the capabilities as below

```
DesiredCapabilities capability;

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
// Set browser language to French 
options.AddArguments("--lang=fr");
capability = (DesiredCapabilities)options.ToCapabilities();

capability.SetCapability("browser", "chrome");
capability.SetCapability("browser_version", "61");
capability.SetCapability("os", "Windows");
capability.SetCapability("os_version", "7");
capability.SetCapability("browserstack.user", "USERNAME");// add username
capability.SetCapability("browserstack.key", "ACCESS_KEY"); //add automate-key

driver = new ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub/"), capability);
```

-For creating a session on Firefox browser include the capabilities as below

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
capability.SetCapability("browser", "Firefox");
capability.SetCapability("browser_version", "63.0");
capability.SetCapability("os", "Windows");
capability.SetCapability("os_version", "10");
capability.SetCapability("browserstack.user", "your_usernmae");
capability.SetCapability("browserstack.key","your_access_key");

FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.SetPreference("intl.accept_languages", "fr");
capability.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, firefoxProfile.ToBase64String());
```

For more information on passing browser options using C# refer - https://www.browserstack.com/automate/c-sharp

Comment: Running your chrome code (I haven't yet tried the Firefox)  generates an Invalid CastException..`System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.ReadOnlyDesiredCapabilities' to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DesiredCapabilities'.'
`   Did the code run succesfully for you?